# pip install from shortened url

Tags: python, pip

I have put my wheel file at `http://long.url.name.com/package-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`, and when I do `pip install http://long.url.name.com/package-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`, it works great. However, when I have a URL shortener forward the above URL and get something like `http://short.url/XYZ`, and try to do `pip install http://short.url/XYZ`, pip doesn't work. I notice the download activity, but I see the following error from pip :

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-2LPqrK-build/setup.py'  
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-2LPqrK-build
```

The problem seems to be that the filename that pip sees for the file is `XYZ`. This is true when I try to download the file using `wget`, for instance. However, when I got to `http://short.url/XYZ`, the file indeed gets downloaded and saved as `package-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`. So how can I make pip work with the shortened URL?

Comment: Also it this seems broke. The -v output is interesting as it gets the redirect and then ignores it

Comment: Same issue, looks like pip may require an enhancement request

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that pip cares about the format of the file at the end of the url

so https://aka.ms/foo-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl works. but if you just have a hask then